HMAC: IV=key instead of concatenation?
$$\text{HMAC}(K, m) = \text{H}((K' \oplus \mathbb{opad}) || \text{H}((K' \oplus \mathbb{ipad}) || m))\\K' = 
\begin{cases} 
\text{H}(K) & \text{if } K \text{ is larger than block size} \\
K & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
This definition takes in a an existing hash function. And assumes Merkle–Damgård construction for the hash since it attempts to prevent length extension attacks.
Suppose instead of concatenating the (key+pad) to the message, you take it as the IV for the MD hash.
$$IV_o = K' \oplus \mathbb{opad}\\
  IV_i = K' \oplus \mathbb{ipad}$$
These replace the constant IV's of the MD hash.
Would such an HMAC be secure?
Also, supposing that the hash is a HAIFA construction (salted/peppered and finalized "MD variant") would using a naive MAC construction where the key goes into the IV be secure?
HMAC(K,m) = H(m) where IV=K and len(Hstate) = len(K)

I'm aware that BLAKE has a keyed variant for this purpose, generalized HAIFA do not.

Using the hash function's IV gives you almost exactly NMAC. Usually NMAC is defined with completely independent keys/IVs, though.

Since $K'$ is a key and since both will differ due to the padding and since the IV could be seen as a previous hash block you could infer some security from that. As your name is "eternalstudent" can we assume this is part of an assignment?

No, I'm not a student.
